# lookup table for hashtags, case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql, case-sensitive

I'm trying to implement hashtag suggestion while a user is typing, So I'm building an hashtag table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hashtags_weight` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hashtag` varchar(140) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `tot` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `hashtag` (`hashtag`,`tot`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

which I'll later query with:

```
SELECT hashtag  FROM hashtags_weight WHERE hashtag LIKE 'foob%' ORDER BY tot DESC
```

the source I'm getting the hashtags from is from previously inserted hashtags. Now, while this is all pretty basic stuff I thought it would be preferrable to suggest an hashtag with the most used case. suppose I have a table with:

```
10 Foobar
5 FooBar
2 foobar
```

this means that 10 times Foobar has been used, 5 FooBar and 2 foobar. now, I'd like to count as 17 the hashtag and propose only Foobar during the autocompletion.

Of course I can do it with some array sorting but I already see that it's taking a lot of time (there are a lot of rows). I'd like to hear some different approach to the matter.

p.s.
this job will run nightly, so there's no need for it to be super fast. I just want to make sure I'm  doing it properly.
of course I could add more table to the Db, no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Update your query:

```
SELECT count(*) as count,hashtag  FROM hashtags_weight WHERE hashtag LIKE 'foob%' GROUP BY hashtag ORDER BY tot DESC
```

Add a count & a group by and it should work since your table is case insensitive already.

Not sure how you got to the 10,5 & 2 already buy I assume you did this with PHP

edit:

I see you use 'tot'. Does this hold the total? In that case:

```
SELECT hashtag,sum(tot) as total FROM hashtags_weight WHERE hashtag LIKE 'foob%' GROUP BY hashtag ORDER BY tot DESC
```

Comment: I'm not doing this where users are adding their hashtags. that is another table. this table is just meant for lookup (it's already a 'view' on its own). so I need to sum 10,5,2 and save the data on hashtags_weight as Foobar, 17